# I want to remove multiple characters from a string input by user

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, strip

I am trying to ask the user for their phone number, and many people type their number such as "123-456-7890", "(123)456-7890".

I want to make the program strip the " ()- " from the input so that when I print the number back to the user, it shows it as 1234567980 without all the extra characters.

So far I have been able to remove only the first parentheses from the string by doing this:

```
number = str(input("Enter phone number: "))
print(number.strip('('))
```

Comment: What stops you from stripping the closing parenthesis, dash, and spaces? Also, replacing with a regex might be better here.

Comment: look at string's .replace() function

Answer (score 2):

Strings are iterable, so your problem can be efficiently solved using a list comprehension.

```
digits = '0123456789'
phone_number = ''.join([x for x in input("Enter phone number: ") if x in digits])
```

The benefit of this approach is that ONLY digits get included in the final result. Whereas with the replace approach you have to specify each and every exclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Edited as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant way to do it but:

```
print(number.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('-', ''))
```

Comment: Oooo yes that works just like I need it to, thank you very much!